# How to make activity transparent in Xamarin android

Tags: xamarin

I have refered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android). But I just see a black background.
Then I use a Android standard Theme "ThemeTranslucentNoTitleBar". It is still a black background. So how to make a activity completely transparent?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        SetTheme(Android.Resource.Style.ThemeTranslucentNoTitleBar);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.xxx);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying lots of times. I find the resolution.  You also have to set Android application theme. For exmaple  `<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />`  If you are using a custom application theme. Do not forget to set android:windowIsTranslucent = true
`<style name="CustomTheme"
         parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
  </style>`